# Migrate Swagger Express project to AWS Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger

I am working on a Swagger Express project. (around 50 API endpoints)

I wanna migrate this project to AWS Serverless which using Lambda.

From
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/tree/master/example, I can see how to migrate from Express project to Serverless. But Swagger Express project seems be different.

Any suggestion or steps I should follow is appreciated.

Comment: Serverless Express is _not_ the same thing as the Serverless Framwork.

Comment: Also looking for this